# how to merge the .net add_on with my outlook

Tags: .net, visual-studio, outlook-addin

i have developed a add-on for Microsoft outlook email  using .net application with visual studio add-in project. .on building the application it produces the dll for the application.now i am not able to get how to merge the
.net add_on  with my outlook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean how do you install it into Outlook?

Did you make it using Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)? If so, right click on the project and go to Properties. There's a publish tab with some options on how to publish a setup website.

If you didn't do that and wrote a COM addin instead, it should have created an installer project as part of the addin. You'll need to build that to create an installer.

Comment: yeah i have created  the installer for that.when i install the installer to install the add-in .i found that the addin found in the outlook 2003 under the disabled items with load behaviour as "not loaded run time error ocurred while loading com add-in" .                                                                    but it doesn't shows exception and works fine when i debug the project.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and the tools are you using? When you made the project, did you pick Outlook 2003 addin? IIRC the default in VS 2008 was for an Outlook 2007 project, which due to the ribbon won't work in 2003.